# User logs out every time app is closed - Firebase Authentication - Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My android application uses firebase authentication. Once the user logs in and is in the app, getCurrentUser() is not null, which is good. But, once the user closes the app, they don't stay logged in.

Here's my code:

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText email, password;
Button signIn, toSignUp;
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    email = findViewById(R.id.insertemail);
    password = findViewById(R.id.checkpassword);
    signIn = findViewById(R.id.signIn);
    toSignUp = findViewById(R.id.toSignUp);
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser mFireBaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(login.this, "You are logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent inte = new Intent(login.this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(inte);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(login.this, "Please log in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String em = email.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            if (em.isEmpty()) {
                email.setError("Please enter your Email ID");
                email.requestFocus();
            } else if (pass.isEmpty()) {
                password.setError("Please enter you Password");
                password.requestFocus();
            } else if (em.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(login.this, "Fields are empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (!(em.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty())) {
                mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(em, pass).addOnCompleteListener(login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Log in Failed. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Intent inten = new Intent(login.this, MapsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(inten);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(login.this, "Error Occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    toSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, signup.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Why is `mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` null every time the app is closed?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The current user is null on a cold start of the app because it takes time (and network connectivity) to determine if that user is valid.  Firebase isn't going to block the launch of the app to determine if the user is valid.  It's going to let your code run ASAP.  The AuthStateListener callback you provide will be invoked whenever the SDK is sure that the user is valid.

If you want to know for sure if the user is signed in or signed out at the time the app is launched, you should wait for the first callback to the listener.  Until then, the sign-in status of the user is unknown, and it probably makes sense to show a spinner or some other wait screen until then.

Comment: I'm slightly confused what you mean by "waiting for the first callback to the listener." It would be great if you could explain

Comment: I'm saying don't make any decisions about what to do until the first time the callback is invoked, since it could take an unknown amount of time for that to happen.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that your auth state listener never even got added using [addAuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)). It will never get invoked until you do that.

Comment: Where should I add addAuthStateListener? I thought that mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() was enough to add the AuthStateListener

Comment: That just declares the listener.  You need to add to somewhere after you declare it using the API I linked above.

Comment: The problem is that once I add "mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);", there is a Null Pointer Exception on "onAuthStateChanged"

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should post a new question.  Stack Overflow only really allows one question per post.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Thank you so much for your help and quick responses!